# react combine differents wrappers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, graphql, i18next

We are starting a new project in React.
And we need to use:

- React Context API
- i18n (react.i18nex)
- GraphQL (Apollo client)
- Redux
- CCS-in-JS (styled-components or aphodite)

The thing is that any of this implementation wraps a component and pass it some props or use functions as children.

And I want to **keep my components as decoupled** and clean as possible.

How can I structure the wrappers?

### Example

Home

```
<Home {...props} />
```

Context:

```
 <ThemeContext.Consumer>
   { theme=> <Home {...theme} programa={theme} /> }
 </ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

i18n:

```
 <I18n>
    {t => <Home text={t("translated text")} /> }
 </I18n>
```

GraphQL:

```
<Query query={GET_PROGRAMA}>
  {({ data }) => <Home data={data} />}
</Query>
```

Redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: "some user"
});


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Home);
```

As you can see, the Home component receives isolated props from many sources.

How can I manage ir and keep it decoupled? There is some kind of *composer*?

Thank you!

Comment: `react-adopt` might be interesting for you! https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert this into an HOC that will handle all of the component wrapping for you:

```
const withWrappers = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
          { theme =>
            <I18n>
              { t =>
                <Query query={GET_PROGRAMA}>
                  { ({ data }) => 
                    <WrappedComponent
                      {...this.props}
                      {...theme}
                      programa={theme}
                      data={data}
                      text={t("translated text")}
                    />
                  }
                </Query>
              }
            </I18n>
          }
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div>Home</div>
      )
    }
}

export default withWrappers(Home);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think is the best approach in the time we have. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! All of you.
I've implemented a HOC, the same as you porposed to me, and keep the GraphQL components outside:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { mergeStyles } from "js/utils";
import { I18n } from "react-i18next";
import { TemplateContext } from "js/template-context";

const Wrapper = ({ Component, getStylesFromTemplate }) => props => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <TemplateContext.Consumer>
      {programa => {
        const { template } = programa;
        const stylesFromTemplate = getStylesFromTemplate(template);
        const styles = mergeStyles({ classes, stylesFromTemplate });
        return (
          <I18n>
            {(t, { i18n }) => {
              return (
                <Component
                  t={t}
                  styles={styles}
                  programa={programa}
                  {...props}
                />
              );
            }}
          </I18n>
        );
      }}
    </TemplateContext.Consumer>
  );
};

Wrapper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Wrapper;
```

Again, thank you so much!